# Accessing docker container from Docker for Mac

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-for-mac

I have the following scenario:

- Mac OS Catalina
- Windows Virtual Machine running on VirtualBox
- Docker for Mac (not docker-machine or Docker Toolbox)

I need to access a port that is exposed with `docker run -p 80:80 nginx` from the Windows VM and nothing seems to work. I tried NAT, bridge, socat... any hints?

Comment: Can you reach your docker container from the Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out.
I can access the docker service by using the bridge interface IP (but not using *localhost*). 
So in essence:

- VM in VirtualBox should run in network bridged mode
- use http://1.2.3.4 in the browser where 1.2.3.4 is your MacOS network interface IP address